# Regex: Negating a whole word (needed to optimize a file)

Tags: java, android, regex, json

I am trying to do a simple weather widget for Android, that provides temperatures just for my country (Jordan). The website I am using for the weather records provides a JSON file with country regions data for many countries. The problem is that the file contains 2500+ objects, and it takes a really long time to be parsed. Thus, and as I actually need <100 of them (the regions of my country), I thought that I could optimize the file before passing it to the JSON parser, by taking off all of the records I don't need. I don't know if it's a good solution, but it was what I thought of. Anyway, my problem now is getting the right Regex.

[This is the URL of the JSON file](http://www.arabiaweather.com/json/Arabia.index.en.json.txt).

As you can see, every object has four items. The one I need to check for is "icon", which specifies the country of that region.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
{"value":"khalda","icon":"Jordan","label":"khalda","desc":"Amman & Madaba"},
```

What I could came up with so far is the pattern of the object I actually *need*. However, I need to get the ones I don't need to be able to delete them. Here is the pattern: `\{[^\{]*Jordan*[^\}]*\},` (This has to be modified so it validates when "Jordan" does NOT exist, which I couldn't figure out.)

Any help/hint is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Even that much JSON should barely take any time at all to parse. How are you parsing it? If it's using a well-known library, I think the bottleneck is probably your internet connection rather than the parsing speed.

Comment: I am using the JSONArray/JSONObject that are built-in in Java. (This was my ref: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/)

EDIT: My internet connection is 8Mbps.

Comment: Hm... okay, but I just parsed that entire thing in JavaScript and it took precisely 27 milliseconds. I stand by my statement :)

Comment: Okay, I may try a different parser then and see the results. What about https://sites.google.com/site/gson/? Do you have any experience with JSON parsers for Java?

Comment: No, actually, I have no Java experience :) Do you have some kind of profiling tool available? It should help you narrow down exactly where the problem is. Otherwise, it's just time to manually compare some dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than matching and deleting the objects you don't need, match and extract the single(?) object that you do need.  It will be faster.

(And I agree with minitech's comment.  Parsing the JSON file is unlikely to be the *real* bottleneck.)

Comment: How can I extract a text according to a specific pattern in Java?

Comment: Well, if you have a regex to match the country you require, you just need to expand the regex to match the whole json object.